# How can i extract dates and events from an excel file which has 2000 rows of text paragraph in it?

Tags: excel, events, text, extract

I need to extract dates and events from an excel file which has 2000 rows

Please refer Image below:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Please formulate your question better.

Comment: What would a typical extracted event be?

Comment: Also how long are the rows, in bytes?

Comment: The rows consists of text like "Transportation authorities in China are calling for more public transportation development to alleviate traffic congestion experienced in major cities throughout the country. The Ministry of Transport has released .." typical extracted events be Event: "Strike" or "Accident" or etc. Date: 12 Jul 2015 or etc..